# Chrome 7 interprets CSS percentage relative positioning differently from Chrome 6 (and other browsers)

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

My Chrome install updated itself last night (without telling or asking me!)

It now interprets CSS percentage relative positioning differently to yesterday. Suppose I have:

```
<body>
  <div class="everything">
    <div class="centerMe">
      Center me!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And this CSS:

```
body
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.everything
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.centerMe
{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

In the version of Chrome I had until last night (6.x), and for that matter in Firefox 3.6.10 and IE 8, the `Center me!` appears roughly in the middle of the page, *vertically and horizontally*.

But in Chrome 7.0.517.41, it is only centred horizontally. Vertically, it is at the top of the page.

Was this change made deliberately to address a long-standing inaccuracy in CSS rendering, or is it a new bug in 7.x that Google will fix soon?

Notes:

- If I take out the `<div class="centerMe">` and corresponding `</div>` then Chrome 7.x obeys the vertical positioning, but Firefox and IE don't! (i.e. browsers all reverse their behaviour).
- If I change the CSS for `.centerMe` to `position: absolute;` all browsers I've tested behave consistently, centring vertically and horizontally. This makes more sense anyway, so would appear to be the sane workaround for anyone who hits this as a problem.
- As always, IE's behaviour is nothing remotely similar unless `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` appears at the start of the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Chrome 7 doesn't calculate implicit height of an absolute-positionned element, as this will work :

```
body
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.everything
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height:100%; /* fix height */
}

.centerMe
{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

I don't see anything in W3C specifications so I think it's a "bug". Anyway this method is bad to center an element ^^